# Prestashop: how to add fields to the order summary page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm working with Prestashop 1.6 and I need to add a checkbox and text field in the order summary page, as shown below.

[image]

I'm lost on which hooks to use to do so. These fields should be also shown in the invoice. For the hook of the invoice I believe it is the `DisplayPDFInvoice` hook, but for the order summary (display and get information) I don't know which hooks to use.

Can you give me some tips? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hook `hookDisplayBeforeShoppingCartBlock` to render any content on cart summary page. Don't forget to register this hook to your module.

I have tried using the same and got the results as below:

[image]

Code:

```
public function hookDisplayBeforeShoppingCartBlock()
{      
    return '<div>Text Area : </div><textarea rows="3" cols="30">This is a text area rendered from hookDisplayBeforeShoppingCartBlock</textarea><br><br><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">checkbox 1<br><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">checkbox 2';
}
```

The above code is used just to show an example, you can render any template file from there. As you can see that this hook renders content above cart block so you can use `javascript` to move it below cart block.

Comment: Welcome :). If it worked for you then you can mark this answer as accepted so that other users can also get help. Thanks.